Cannot bind parameter 'RemainingScripts'
I'm trying to write contacts from a CSV to the web interface for a Cisco phone. The script is-
Script
Error
Any help is greatly appreciated!
This script was originally designed to run in Python, however, Python isn't native to our environment, so a conversion was necessary.
I apologize for dropping snippets, I felt like raw code made this post muddy.
Script-
# Define the phone ID and the Cisco URL
$phone_id = '10.45.210.166'
$cisco_url = "https://$phone_id/addContact"

# Define the parameters
$params = @('name', 'workPhone', 'key', 'ringTone')

# Import the CSV file
$csv_file = Import-Csv -Path 'phone-list.csv' -Header 'Name', 'Number'

# Loop through each row in the CSV file
foreach ($row in $csv_file) {
    # Skip the header row
    if ($row.Name -eq 'Name') {
        continue
    }

    # Prepare the data for the POST request
    $data = @{
        'name'       = $row.Name
        'workPhone'  = $row.Number
        'key'        = '0'  # Assuming a default value for 'key'
        'ringTone'   = '1'  # Assuming a default value for 'ringTone'
    }

    # Convert the data to URL-encoded format
    $encodedData = $data | ForEach-Object { "$($_.Key)=$($_.Value)" } -join '&'

    # Send the POST request
    Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $cisco_url -Method Post -Body $encodedData -ContentType 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -SkipCertificateCheck

    # Wait for 0.5 seconds
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 0.5
}

error-
ForEach-Object : Cannot bind parameter 'RemainingScripts'. Cannot convert the "-join" value of type "System.String" to
type "System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock".
At line:27 char:28
+ ... edData = $data | ForEach-Object { "$($_.Key)=$($_.Value)" } -join '&'
+                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [ForEach-Object], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ForEachObjectCommand

Invoke-RestMethod : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'SkipCertificateCheck'.
At line:30 char:120
+ ... ContentType 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -SkipCertificateCheck
+                                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-RestMethod], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand


Please post your code and error message(s) as plain text, not screenshots (we can help format the code so your post looks less "muddy")

Probably need extra parentheses around the thing being joined.

@MathiasR.Jessen edited for the sake of clarity.
Thank you :)

-skipcertificatecheck is powershell 7 only

In the instance where someone lands in this same situation, the resolution for this was to add the following above the script-
Add-Type @"
using System.Net;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

public class TrustAllCertsPolicy : ICertificatePolicy {
  public bool CheckValidationResult(ServicePoint srvPoint, X509Certificate certificate, WebRequest request, int certificateProblem)
  { return true; }
}
"@

